# Django: Update model fields using ajax call from template

Tags: python, ajax, django

I have a model:

```
class ok(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    project = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    story = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    depends_on = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')
    rfc = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I have model form.

```
class okForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
     model = ok
     fields='__all__'
```

I am getting first 3 fields: name, project, story user manual entry. Now I want to populate the last two fields with respect to third field using AJAX call from views function that will query to mysql database. 
I have a fucntion in views.py

```
def get(self, request):
    name = request.GET.get('name')
    project = request.GET.get('project')
    story = request.GET.get('story')
    if name and project and story:
        try:
            obj = ok.objects.get(name=name, project=project, story=story)
            return JsonResponse(data={
                'depends_on': ok_obj.depends_on,
                'rfc': ok_obj.rfc}, status=200)
        except ok.DoesNotExist:
             pass
    return JsonResponse(data={'error': 'bad request'}, status=400)
```

How i will make the ajax call with the third value the user just filled, as he has not submitted the form yet .

Kindly help.

Comment: Could you elaborate your actual requirement?

Comment: What do you mean by ajax call from views?

Comment: i need to make a ajax call to the 'get' function with the third field 'story' to the function as input , so thet i can make a mysql query with it

Comment: You mean ajax call from your template to views. Right?

Comment: I think you have already done that in your existing code.

Comment: ajax('/path/get', data, function (result)) this way i have to make a call to 'get' function with 'story' value from the form field as input

Comment: how can i make the call from template

Comment: You shouldn't use a get call to make changes in the db anyway.

Comment: As @DanielRoseman said , we don't use get request for db changing things. Try POST request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, in your template, do -

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="get_value()" name="third_value" />

<script>
    function get_value(){
      var val=document.getElementsByName("third_value")[0].value;
      var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("GET","get_value_url?value="+val,true);
      xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
         if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
            var res=JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            // do something with this response like autofill
         }
      }
      xhr.send(null);
}
</script>
```

Where as your view will look similar to what you already have. Like -

```
def get(request):
   val = request.GET["value"]
   # query your db and prepare response data
   return JsonResponse(response)
```

Of course you would want to set some timeout in your template so that it does not query everytime user presses a button.

Hope this helps.

Comment: now i am getting  following erro::                                                                                            raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))
MultiValueDictKeyError: "u'third_value'"

Comment: Follow the edited post. Actually the variable in which value is stored is `value`.

Comment: still getting same error :                                                                                        val=request.GET["value"]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 85, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))
MultiValueDictKeyError: "u'value'"

Comment: Could you just post the value of `request.GET` here by printing it?

Comment: its <QueryDict: {u'username': [u'hero']}>