# ajax call in django with field detect in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

i have a model

```
 class name(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
      project = models.CharField(max_length=255)
      story = models.CharField(max_length=500)
      depends_on = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')
      rfc = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I have a view:

```
def get(request):
   val=request.GET.get("username")
   print val
   response=name.objects.filter(story='{}'.format(val))
   print response[0].rfc
   return HttpResponse(response)
```

I have model form:

```
   class nameForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
       model = Manifest
       fields = "__all__"
```

In template user have to drop down some choices in the first three fields name, project,story . Now i want to detect what user has droped down
for the third field 'story'. So that i can make a ajax call with that value just user drop down on third field ,  to the function 'get' .

How can i do it with ajax and js .

Kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesterday I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47548076/4428377).

For your template -

```
<select onchange="get_value()" name="third_value">
    <option value="val"></option>
</select>

<script>
    function get_value(){
      var val=document.getElementsByName("third_value")[0].value;
      var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("GET","get_value_url?value="+val,true);
      xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
         if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
            var res=JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            // do something with this response like autofill
         }
      }
      xhr.send(null);
}
</script>
```

Where as your view will look similar to what you already have. Like -

```
def get(request):
   val = request.GET["value"]
   # query your db and prepare response data
   return JsonResponse(response)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: user is not typing anything on the third field . he just selecting choices

Comment: That was my copy-paste mistake. Sorry for that. See the edited post, however not much has changed. You get the idea, right?